# How to wait until form is fully loaded HTML to PDF In MVC

Tags: c#, angularjs, model-view-controller

I am using epfhtmltopdf dll for converting HTML to pdf wherein the page is getting rendered but we have a graph on the page which is called by angular js after getting Id of DIV element but not getting reflected in the pdf because page gets render but chart comes after 2 seconds. I have also used the property

pdfConverter.ConversionDelay = 20;

but still, it is taking time but no luck
Please help
Here is the given code:

```
 public void DownloadPDF(int? ReportLogId, int? StockID)
    {
        string baseUrl = Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Authority + Request.ApplicationPath.TrimEnd('/') + "/";
        string urlToConvert = baseUrl + "CompanyResearch/Index?ReportLogId=" + ReportLogId + "&StockID=" + StockID;

        PdfConverter pdfConverter = new PdfConverter();

        pdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.PdfPageSize = PdfPageSize.A4;
        pdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.PdfCompressionLevel = PdfCompressionLevel.Normal;
        pdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.ShowHeader = true;
        pdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.ShowFooter = true;
        pdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.LeftMargin = 5;
        pdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.RightMargin = 5;
        pdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.TopMargin = 5;
        pdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.BottomMargin = 5;
        pdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.GenerateSelectablePdf = true;
        pdfConverter.RenderOnTimeout = true;

        pdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.ShowHeader = false;
        //pdfConverter.PdfHeaderOptions.HeaderText = "Sample header: " + TxtURL.Text;
        //pdfConverter.PdfHeaderOptions.HeaderTextColor = Color.Blue;
        //pdfConverter.PdfHeaderOptions.HeaderDescriptionText = string.Empty;
        //pdfConverter.PdfHeaderOptions.DrawHeaderLine = false;

        pdfConverter.PdfFooterOptions.FooterText = "Sample footer: " + urlToConvert +
        ". You can change color, font and other options";
        pdfConverter.PdfFooterOptions.FooterTextColor = Color.Blue;
        pdfConverter.PdfFooterOptions.DrawFooterLine = false;
        pdfConverter.PdfFooterOptions.PageNumberText = "Page";
        pdfConverter.PdfFooterOptions.ShowPageNumber = true;
        pdfConverter.ConversionDelay = 20;


        //pdfConverter.LicenseKey = "put your serial number here";
        byte[] downloadBytes = pdfConverter.GetPdfBytesFromUrl(urlToConvert);




        // byte[] Bytes = pdfConverter.GetPdfFromUrlBytes(urlToConvert);



        System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
        response.Clear();
        response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "binary/octet-stream");
        response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition",
        "attachment; filename=" + "DownloadedPDF.pdf" + "; size=" + downloadBytes.Length.ToString());
        response.Flush();
        response.BinaryWrite(downloadBytes);
        response.Flush();
        response.End();


    }
```

Thanks,

Ritesh

Comment: Here i have used jquery amchart and binding chart using Div element with ID.      epfhtmltopdf is just used for creating pdf of html ,what ever the content will load on html.

Comment: is it only with charts or any content that is updated later via Javascript? I suspect any change to the DOM is not taken into account.. can you confirm ?

Comment: yes, after DOM loaded i am calling chart from javascript

Comment: That was not my question... okay try this.. change the color of a Div using javascript and see if that is coming correctly in PDF..

Comment: Where is your angular code?

Answer (score 0):

From FAQ: http://www.html-to-pdf.net/FAQ.aspx

The PdfConverter has the following properties controlling the JavaScript, Java Applets and ActiveX download and execution during conversion: ScriptsEnabled, ScriptsEnabledInImage, ActiveXEnabled, ActiveXEnabledInImage. By default these properties are false which means the JavaScript code is not enabled during conversion. To activate JavaScript simply set `PdfConverter.ScriptsEnabled = true` when converting to PDF with selectable text or set `PdfConverter.ScriptsEnabledInImage = true` when converting to PDF with embedded image.

Comment: Thanks for reply but not getting actually I am calling all the table and content using angularjs ng-repeat and on the event of repeat end i am calling chart and binding it to div element. Here when i am creating pdf of page then the table and content is coming in pdf but chart is not coming. i think pdf method gets execute before chart render.

Comment: I have enabled both things which you have given. 
                    pdfConverter.ScriptsEnabled = true;
            pdfConverter.ScriptsEnabledInImage = true;  But not working

Comment: Then I suggest you try @RajshekarReddy s approach and do a simple javascript change and see if it reflects in the Pdf, to narrow it down a bit.

Comment: Yes, when i changed the color of that div using java script just before rendering chart then it is coming in pdf.